# Special character issue in json response using okhttp

Tags: android, json, okhttp

There is GET service from which I am getting response.

URL:http://52.33.140.142:8080/TigerServlet/?command=GetAlerts&email=brinda@gmail.com&hours=0&tag=Android&device_token=APA91bHm-hjBFN-V9ygCJbSd6Bqo6ww27a_Z0tfxnsdbLiBC0TP03HpkLohThzL0bE69G_uBzId-kkIPnORdIe1LzA_no9h93HaawdAprbQhBRVo0QCtzz400PdoWWMBMBtmlXqGFwyV&language=en

==>Response: When I open above URL in browser like google chrome.

```
{ "success":"1", "data": [ { "address": "Hôtel de Ville, 75004 Paris, France", "email": "umesh.nepali@indianic.com", "username": "umeshfinal", "phone": "9033329824", "status": 0, "fld_help_id": 97979, "recieveremail": "brinda@gmail.com", "image": "http://services.defensealertdevice.com/admin/uploads/user_image/user_image_2094.png", "latitude": "48.8564817", "longitude": "2.3524133", "datetime": "2017-03-03 10:50:03.0", "alertType": 0 }, { "address": "Skíðabraut, Dalvík, Iceland", "email": "brinda@gmail.com", "username": "chil", "phone": "1234567890", "status": 0, "fld_help_id": 97981, "recieveremail": "brinda@gmail.com", "image": "http://services.defensealertdevice.com/admin/uploads/user_image/user_image_2843.png", "latitude": "65.9667", "longitude": "-18.5333", "datetime": "2017-03-03 10:34:51.0", "alertType": 4 }, } ], "message": "" }
```

==>Response: When I open above URL in rest client like postman.

```
{ "success":"1" "data": [ { "address": "H�tel de Ville, 75004 Paris, France", "email": "umesh.nepali@indianic.com", "username": "umeshfinal", "phone": "9033329824", "status": 0, "fld_help_id": 97979, "recieveremail": "brinda@gmail.com", "image": "http://services.defensealertdevice.com/admin/uploads/user_image/user_image_2094.png", "latitude": "48.8564817", "longitude": "2.3524133", "datetime": "2017-03-03 10:50:03.0", "alertType": 0 }, { "address": "Sk��abraut, Dalv�k, Iceland", "email": "brinda@gmail.com", "username": "chil", "phone": "1234567890", "status": 0, "fld_help_id": 97981, "recieveremail": "brinda@gmail.com", "image": "http://services.defensealertdevice.com/admin/uploads/user_image/user_image_2843.png", "latitude": "65.9667", "longitude": "-18.5333", "datetime": "2017-03-03 10:34:51.0", "alertType": 4 }, } ], "message": "" }
```

==>I am using okhttp for network calling and in okhttp utf-8 is supported by default. ==>On server(tomcat) side also set utf-8.

==>Still I am getting �=\ufffd unicode instead of actual unicode of special character.]

==>Also I did the conversion process like URLDecoder.decode("string").

==>Still I would not able to get actual special character.

==>I can't understand whether this issue from android side or server side.

Comment: Print the response headers? The Content-Type header might offer a hint.

Comment: Response header: Request{method=GET, url=http://52.33.140.142:8080/TigerServlet?command=GetAlerts&email=brinda@gmail.com&hours=0&tag=Android&device_token=APA91bHm-hjBFN-V9ygCJbSd6Bqo6ww27a_Z0tfxnsdbLiBC0TP03HpkLohThzL0bE69G_uBzId-kkIPnORdIe1LzA_no9h93HaawdAprbQhBRVo0QCtzz400PdoWWMBMBtmlXqGFwyV&language=en, tag=null}

Comment: Print the response headers? That’s the response, not its headers.

Comment: D/Header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
D/Header: Content-Length: 185
D/Header: Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 07:08:31 GMT
D/Header: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1489216112101
D/Header: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1489216112377
D/Header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
D/Header: Content-Length: 5989
D/Header: Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 07:08:47 GMT
D/Header: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1489216127284
D/Header: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1489216127686

Answer (score -1):

After spending one month , I have resolved this issue.Actually this issue  from the server side .We have to set the meta tag on server side.

Happy Coding.

Comment: How could I set meta tag in server side? Kindly elaborate this.